# Create programmatically a WooCommerce product variation with new attribute values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

I have created a variable product ("parent" product) in WooCommerce version 3+. From a WordPress plugin, I would like to programmatically create the product variations ("children" product) with new attribute values.

The variation attributes are already set in WooCommerce. 
So every time one variation is created, the new attribute's values should be created programmatically too and set in the parent Variable product.

How can this be done? is it possible?

---

Update : *I had written more lines of code on this that I wished, and tried many things to solve it, using woocommerce objects, and added missing data about terms, termmeta, the relationship from term with post, in the database using the WordPress database object - but nothing has sufficed to make it work. And I couldn't pin-point where I went wrong - that is why I couldn't provide a narrower problem - things for which stackoverflow is more made for.*

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Comment: You should close one of these - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/how-to-create-a-variable-product-programmatically-with-two-new-variante-attribut

Comment: Although I personally think this is a fair question as is, it would have been more useful to provide at least your best attempt. That could guide others not only in terms of helping you, but also those facing the same issue

Comment: @MikeA I understand, and that is what I usually do when I write a question on Stackoverflow. But for this specific one, in this case, providing my best attempts would have resulted in 2 big chunk of code that would have been definitely counter-productive to the community. You can trust me on that one!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> **Update January 2020:** Changed to [`WC_Product` method `get_name()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_name) instead of `get_title()`
> **Update September 2018:** Handling taxonomy creation *(Thanks to Carl F. Corneil)*

From a defined variable product ID You will find below, a custom function that will add (create) a Product variation. The variable parent product needs to have set for it the needed attributes.

You will need to provide some information as:

- the array of attributes/values
- the Sku, prices and stock….

This data has to be stored in a formatted multi dimensional array *(see an example at the end)*.

This function will check if the attributes values (term name) already exist and if not:

- it create it for the product attribute
- set it in the parent variable product.

The custom function code:

```
/**
 * Create a product variation for a defined variable product ID.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @param int   $product_id | Post ID of the product parent variable product.
 * @param array $variation_data | The data to insert in the product.
 */

function create_product_variation( $product_id, $variation_data ){
    // Get the Variable product object (parent)
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    $variation_post = array(
        'post_title'  => $product->get_name(),
        'post_name'   => 'product-'.$product_id.'-variation',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_parent' => $product_id,
        'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
        'guid'        => $product->get_permalink()
    );

    // Creating the product variation
    $variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation_post );

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
    $variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

    // Iterating through the variations attributes
    foreach ($variation_data['attributes'] as $attribute => $term_name )
    {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$attribute; // The attribute taxonomy

        // If taxonomy doesn't exists we create it (Thanks to Carl F. Corneil)
        if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ){
            register_taxonomy(
                $taxonomy,
               'product_variation',
                array(
                    'hierarchical' => false,
                    'label' => ucfirst( $attribute ),
                    'query_var' => true,
                    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => sanitize_title($attribute) ), // The base slug
                ),
            );
        }

        // Check if the Term name exist and if not we create it.
        if( ! term_exists( $term_name, $taxonomy ) )
            wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy ); // Create the term

        $term_slug = get_term_by('name', $term_name, $taxonomy )->slug; // Get the term slug

        // Get the post Terms names from the parent variable product.
        $post_term_names =  wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'names') );

        // Check if the post term exist and if not we set it in the parent variable product.
        if( ! in_array( $term_name, $post_term_names ) )
            wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, $term_name, $taxonomy, true );

        // Set/save the attribute data in the product variation
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, $term_slug );
    }

    ## Set/save all other data

    // SKU
    if( ! empty( $variation_data['sku'] ) )
        $variation->set_sku( $variation_data['sku'] );

    // Prices
    if( empty( $variation_data['sale_price'] ) ){
        $variation->set_price( $variation_data['regular_price'] );
    } else {
        $variation->set_price( $variation_data['sale_price'] );
        $variation->set_sale_price( $variation_data['sale_price'] );
    }
    $variation->set_regular_price( $variation_data['regular_price'] );

    // Stock
    if( ! empty($variation_data['stock_qty']) ){
        $variation->set_stock_quantity( $variation_data['stock_qty'] );
        $variation->set_manage_stock(true);
        $variation->set_stock_status('');
    } else {
        $variation->set_manage_stock(false);
    }
    
    $variation->set_weight(''); // weight (reseting)

    $variation->save(); // Save the data
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Usage (example with 2 attributes):

```
$parent_id = 746; // Or get the variable product id dynamically

// The variation data
$variation_data =  array(
    'attributes' => array(
        'size'  => 'M',
        'color' => 'Green',
    ),
    'sku'           => '',
    'regular_price' => '22.00',
    'sale_price'    => '',
    'stock_qty'     => 10,
);

// The function to be run
create_product_variation( $parent_id, $variation_data );
```

Tested and works.

> **Part 2:** [Create programmatically a variable product and two new attributes in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/create-programmatically-a-variable-product-and-two-new-attributes-in-woocommerce/47844054#47844054)

You will get this in backend:

[image]

And it will work perfectly in front end.

> **Related:** [Create programmatically a product using CRUD methods in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937409/create-programmatically-a-product-using-crud-methods-in-woocommerce-3/52941994#52941994)

Comment: The stock could be 0 - so perhaps we shouldn't have  :: if( ! empty($variation_data['stock_qty']) ){  ::but :: if (isset($variation_data['stock_qty']) && is_numeric($variation_data['stock_qty'])) {

Comment: I have added some data - weight (if I am not wrong, a variation could have a different weight than the parent/variable or other variation), description, slug .

Comment: if (is_numeric(($variation_data['weight'])))
            $variation->set_weight($variation_data['weight']);
        if (is_string(($variation_data['long_description'])) && strlen($variation_data['long_description']))
            $variation->set_description($variation_data['long_description']);
        if (is_string(($variation_data['slug'])) && strlen($variation_data['slug']))
            $variation->set_slug($variation_data['slug']);

Comment: once we have clarified the above note, you could add a dummy answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/how-to-create-a-variable-product-programmatically-with-two-new-variante-attribut - by solving the product-variation-with-new-attribute-value post, you have solved for me the other one. So I could attribute you the other post's bounty too.

Comment: @LiocTheAztec  I find some code is usually acceptable, but sure, no problem. I've posted my suggestion as a new answer, hopefully you or others will find it useful. Thanks for your code, it worked great!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Thanks for the solutions you save my day and most of all things are working fine as per your above code. It's really need help full to me.

Comment: This answer makes no sense to me. You say to put it in your functions.php file, but that is run on every page load. Surely this is going to constantly add the variations over and over?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat What is the relationship with mustard? This answer answers a question and is useful to many. If it doesn't fit your needs there is many other related threads on internet.

Comment: Above code works great, be careful, for some reason the prices must be string, not integer. The same code worked for for product with integer, but for variation needs to be string. sale_price, regular_price, etc

Comment: it will be great if you could please let me know how can i create $variation_data if i have data in that manner imgur.com/cT1sFGJ

Comment: what add_action do I have to use for my plugin? this is for functions.php file

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Doesn't work for me using WP 5.3.1 and WC 3.8.0, i'm getting **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_title() on boolean in wp-content/themes/x/functions.php:308**. Line 308 is this  **'post_title'  => $product->get_title(),**

Comment: @RichardMišenčík Change it simply to `'post_title' => $product->get_name()`… see it on `WC_Product` [related method documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_name)

Comment: This is actually working on WooCommerce 4.3.1, but on the backend, you need to click "Update" button in order for you to see the correct labeling of the child products

Comment: @LoicTheAztec can you help me? please
I have successfully created a taxonomy attribute and added in `woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` now I want to attach that attribute to all products where  product's `taxonomy = 'pa_color' ` using `SQL` please guide me.

Comment: @SaadAbbasi Product Attributes are a very special custom taxonomy and it's not possible to attach them with an SQL query as the data to be included in the variable product is an indexed multidimensional array under `_product_attributes` meta key

Comment: @LoicTheAztec which approach will you recommend?

Comment: This requires PHP to format the data in an array of `WC_Product_Attribute`  objects and set it in the variable product via `set_product_attributes()` method + `save()` method

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i given variant product id and attributes array like you mentioned, but on product edit page attribute are not showing and varaitions are also not made. Can you help me ?

Comment: data saved but not showing in product view or edit.

Comment: instead of using the prefix 'pa_' hardcoded you should use the built-in woocommerce function wc_attribute_taxonomy_name. see https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_attribute_taxonomy_name

Comment: what is the type of attributes value(ex. M , Green) name or slug ?

Comment: Mostly working as per @Elland's comment, on the backend, you need to click "Update" button in order for you to see the correct labeling of the child products.

Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: See @xmpi's answer - he advise on setting a default attribute, for WC 3.0

Answer (score 18):

I'm just going to throw this out there, since i couldn't get any of the above examples working. Don't ask me why as other people seem to have success. So, i took the minimalist approach and tried to figure out the bare essentials for a product attribute + variation (by creating it manually in wp and looking at the db) and came up with this.

```
$article_name = 'Test';

$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_title' => $article_name,
    'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => "product",
) );
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'variable', 'product_type' );

$attr_label = 'Test attribute';
$attr_slug = sanitize_title($attr_label);

$attributes_array[$attr_slug] = array(
    'name' => $attr_label,
    'value' => 'alternative 1 | alternative 2',
    'is_visible' => '1',
    'is_variation' => '1',
    'is_taxonomy' => '0' // for some reason, this is really important       
);
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', $attributes_array );

$parent_id = $post_id;
$variation = array(
    'post_title'   => $article_name . ' (variation)',
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'post_parent'  => $parent_id,
    'post_type'    => 'product_variation'
);

$variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', 2 );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', 2 );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_stock_qty', 10 );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_' . $attr_slug, 'alternative 1' );
WC_Product_Variable::sync( $parent_id );

$variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', 2 );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', 2 );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_stock_qty', 10 );
update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_' . $attr_slug, 'alternative 2' );
WC_Product_Variable::sync( $parent_id );
```

This is not using global product attributes, but article specific ones. Hope it helps someone as i was about ready to tear my hair out before i got it working.

EDIT: I'd say only use this if you can't get the official methods working. They change these things with time (field names such as '_regular_price" and so on) and chances are it's not super future proof to do it this way.

Comment: I am working with this script but getting error "Invalid value posted for attribute" and product is not added to the cart. how can we solve the issue?

Comment: This is kind of outside the scope of this answer, but if i had to guess i'd say that the variation attribute of the specific variant doesn't match the attributes you assigned it could have (like "alternative 1 | alternative 2"). Either way, we're dealing with updating meta fields directly on the post level here and honestly this (my solution) should really be a last resort unless you really can't get it working with the methods provided by the official WooCommerce API. Try looking at the product at the database level (phpmyadmin or such).

Comment: I've had the best success with a strategy similar to yours (insert a 'product_variation' post, and then set its metadata).

Comment: How  can i add variation image here

Comment: My best guess is you would need to use a combination of adding the image to your media library using the normal wordpress API and then using the set_image_id method of a variation like this; https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product-Variation.html#method_set_image_id

Answer (score 17):

Not sure why, but none of these solutions worked for me, so I decided to create my own:

```
<?php
/**
 * Create a variable product on woocommerce
 * @return int Product ID
 */
function pricode_create_product(){
    $product = new WC_Product_Variable();
    $product->set_description('T-shirt variable description');
    $product->set_name('T-shirt variable');
    $product->set_sku('test-shirt');
    $product->set_price(1);
    $product->set_regular_price(1);
    $product->set_stock_status();
    $product->save();
    return $product;
}

/**
 * Create Product Attributes 
 * @param  string $name    Attribute name
 * @param  array $options Options values
 * @return Object          WC_Product_Attribute 
 */
function pricode_create_attributes( $name, $options ){
    $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
    $attribute->set_id(0);
    $attribute->set_name($name);
    $attribute->set_options($options);
    $attribute->set_visible(true);
    $attribute->set_variation(true);
    return $attribute;
}

/**
 * [pricode_create_variations description]
 * @param  [type] $product_id [description]
 * @param  [type] $values     [description]
 * @return [type]             [description]
 */
function pricode_create_variations( $product_id, $values, $data ){
    $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
    $variation->set_parent_id( $product_id );
    $variation->set_attributes($values);
    $variation->set_status('publish');
    $variation->set_sku($data->sku);
    $variation->set_price($data->price);
    $variation->set_regular_price($data->price);
    $variation->set_stock_status();
    $variation->save();
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $product->save();

}
//Adding product
$product = pricode_create_product();

//Creating Attributes 
$atts = [];
$atts[] = pricode_create_attributes('color',['red', 'green']);
$atts[] = pricode_create_attributes('size',['S', 'M']);

//Adding attributes to the created product
$product->set_attributes( $atts );
$product->save();

//Setting data (following Alexander's rec
$data = new stdClass();
$data->sku = 'sku-123';
$data->price = '10';
//Create variations
pricode_create_variations( $product->get_id(), ['color' => 'red', 'size' => 'M'], $data );
```

Hope it can help others.

Comment: Confirm, other solution didn't work for me.
I am on Woocommerce 5.5.2 and Wordpress 5.8 and this solution works like a charm. Thank you @alejandro-giraldo !

Comment: This have issue with taxonomies (Products -> Attributes). For predefined attributes:



```php
$taxName = 'colour';
$id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name($taxName);
$taxonomy   = 'pa_colour'; // The taxonomy
$term_name  = "black"; // The term
$term_id    = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, $taxonomy )->term_id;
$atts[] = pricode_create_attributes(  $taxonomy ,[$term_id], $id);
```

`pricode_create_variations( $product->get_id(), ['pa_colour' => 'black', 'pa_size' => 'm']);`

Comment: you might be right, I did this for a specific trouble that I had, and didn't need basic attributes , but is totally functional for custom taxonomies. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: where does $data in pricode_create_variations come from?
It is not set anywhere.

Comment: @AlexanderBehling you were right, I did solution for a specific trouble that I had on a project, and the data was added from an API, I just added a change in the code, for the rest of the people which could be looking answers for this. Thanks!

Comment: `$attribute->set_id( 0 )` -- 0 is used bc the docs say `0 for product level attributes`: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-abstracts-abstract-wc-product.html#source-view.1098

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on LoicTheAztec's answer, you can check if the attribute combination exists with the following modification to his code.

```
function create_update_product_variation( $product_id, $variation_data ){

    if(isset($variation_data['variation_id'])) {

      $variation_id = $variation_data['variation_id'];

    } else {

      // if the variation doesn't exist then create it

      // Get the Variable product object (parent)
      $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

      $variation_post = array(
          'post_title'  => $product->get_title(),
          'post_name'   => 'product-'.$product_id.'-variation',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'post_parent' => $product_id,
          'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
          'guid'        => $product->get_permalink()
      );

      // Creating the product variation
      $variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation_post );

    }

    // ...

}
```

Example usage

```
// The variation data
$variation_data =  array(
    'attributes' => array(
        'size'  => 'M',
        'color' => 'Green',
    ),
    'sku'           => '',
    'regular_price' => '22.00',
    'sale_price'    => '1',
    'stock_qty'     => 1,
);

// check if variation exists
$meta_query = array();
foreach ($variation_data['attributes'] as $key => $value) {
  $meta_query[] = array(
    'key' => 'attribute_pa_' . $key,
    'value' => $value
  );
}

$variation_post = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'product_variation',
  'numberposts' => 1,
  'post_parent'   => $parent_id,
  'meta_query' =>  $meta_query
));

if($variation_post) {
  $variation_data['variation_id'] = $variation_post[0]->ID;
}

create_update_product_variation( $product_id, $variation_data );
```

Comment: it will be great if you could please let me know how can i create $variation_data if i have data in that manner https://imgur.com/cT1sFGJ

Comment: Great addition, but does not find attributes with spaces (e.g. color: "Royal Blue") because postmeta is stored as slugs. Fix: `'value' => sanitize_title($value)` (convert $value to slug)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to generate products for testing in WooCommerce, you can use **WooCommerce Smooth Generator**, made by WooCommerce itself.

https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-smooth-generator

Example:

```
// Generate WC_Product object and save it to database
// 70% change generated product is simple
// 30% chance generated product is variable
$product = \WC\SmoothGenerator\Generator\Product::generate();

// Returns WC_Product object of Simple product and don't save it  to database
$product = \WC\SmoothGenerator\Generator\Product::generate_simple_product();

// Returns WC_Product object of Variable Product and saves it to database
$variable_product = \WC\SmoothGenerator\Generator\Product::generate_variable_product();
```

Src: https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-smooth-generator/blob/master/includes/Generator/Product.php

If you want to create products programatically, you can Product class with your needs.

Comment: That's the best solution, using the WooCommerce standards.

Answer (score 2):

it works but needs a little corrections (2 commas in the fuctions array), I did edit some of the code to my needs.

(working on wp 4.9 | wc 3.5)

First the products needs to have the attribute already created and associated, my taxonomy is "pa_r" friendly name "R"
[backend attribute associeated img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SX8j.png)

the function with the correction

```
function create_product_variation( $product_id, $variation_data ){
// Get the Variable product object (parent)
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);

$variation_post = array(
    'post_title'  => $product->get_title(),
    'post_name'   => 'product-'.$product_id.'-variation',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => $product_id,
    'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
    'guid'        => $product->get_permalink()
);

// Creating the product variation
$variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation_post );

// Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

// Iterating through the variations attributes
foreach ($variation_data['attributes'] as $attribute => $term_name )
{
    $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$attribute; // The attribute taxonomy

    // If taxonomy doesn't exists we create it (Thanks to Carl F. Corneil)
    if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ){
        register_taxonomy(
            $taxonomy,
            'product_variation',
            array(
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'label' => ucfirst( $taxonomy ),
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '$taxonomy') // The base slug
            )
        );
    }

    // Check if the Term name exist and if not we create it.
    if( ! term_exists( $term_name, $taxonomy ) )
        wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy ); // Create the term

    $term_slug = get_term_by('name', $term_name, $taxonomy )->slug; // Get the term slug

    // Get the post Terms names from the parent variable product.
    $post_term_names =  wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'names') );

    // Check if the post term exist and if not we set it in the parent variable product.
    if( ! in_array( $term_name, $post_term_names ) )
        wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, $term_name, $taxonomy, true );

    // Set/save the attribute data in the product variation
    update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, $term_slug );
}

## Set/save all other data

// SKU
if( ! empty( $variation_data['sku'] ) )
    $variation->set_sku( $variation_data['sku'] );

// Prices
if( empty( $variation_data['sale_price'] ) ){
    $variation->set_price( $variation_data['regular_price'] );
} else {
    $variation->set_price( $variation_data['sale_price'] );
    $variation->set_sale_price( $variation_data['sale_price'] );
}
$variation->set_regular_price( $variation_data['regular_price'] );

// Stock
if( ! empty($variation_data['stock_qty']) ){
    $variation->set_stock_quantity( $variation_data['stock_qty'] );
    $variation->set_manage_stock(true);
    $variation->set_stock_status('');
} else {
    $variation->set_manage_stock(false);
}

$variation->set_weight(''); // weight (reseting)

$variation->save(); // Save the data
}
```

I made an array with the data I need in the variations [id_post, attribute, sku, regular_price, stock]

```
$hijos = array(
[9623,'265/70 R16','NE-CT-CO-USA-016-005','0',53],
[9624,'235/65 R17','NE-AU-CO-EUR-017-050','189000',56]
);
```

and the foreach to create dynamically all the variations to my products

```
foreach ($hijos as $vari) {
// The variation data
$variation_data =  array(
    'attributes' => array(
        'r'  => $vari[1],
    ),
    'sku'           => $vari[2],
    'regular_price' => str_replace('.', '', $vari[3]),
    'stock_qty'     => $vari[4]
);
// var_dump($variation_data);
create_product_variation( $vari[0], $variation_data );
}
```

Comment: how can i create variation data from the given data

if have product id attribute name, options , plus or minus, price


1647  Copper Gskt   No  +  0.0000<br>
1647  Copper Gskt   Yes  +  14.9500<br>
1647  Drain Line        No  +  0.0000<br>
1647  Drain Line       Yes  +  3.0000<br>
1647  Feed Line  No  +  0.0000<br>
1647  Feed Line  Yes  +  45.0000<br>
1647  Drain Line  No  +  0.0000<br>
1647  Drain Line  Yes  +  45.0000<br>

Comment: in your array [id_post, attribute, sku, regular_price, stock] what about the attribute values for example. colors is an attribute and black red white are the attribute values

Comment: which add_action do I have to use?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, i'm getting **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_title() on boolean in wp-content/themes/x/functions.php:308**. Line 308 is this  **'post_title'  => $product->get_title(),**

Answer (score 1):

You might run into a problem here if the the taxonomy of the product is not registered beforehand somewhere else. If you want to make sure the taxonomy exists, you could add a conditional to LoicTheAztec's answer.

Something like this.

```
foreach ($variation_data['attributes'] as $attribute => $term_name )
{
    //echo 'attribute ' . $attribute . ' term name ' . $term_name;

    $taxonomy = 'pa_' . $attribute; // The attribute taxonomy

    // Check if the Taxonomy exists, and if not we create it.

    if (! taxonomy_exists($taxonomy)){
        register_taxonomy(  
            $taxonomy,  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces). 
            'product',        //post type name
            array(  
                'hierarchical' => false,  
                'label' => ucfirst($taxonomy),  //Display name
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => $taxonomy, // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                    'with_front' => false // Don't display the category base before 
                ),
            )  
        ); 

    }
...
```

Comment: how to prepare variation_data?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Alejandro Giraldo answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62986673/9271344) to use taxonomies instead of custom product attributes you can use this modified version

```
<?php
/**
 * Create a variable product on woocommerce
 * @return int Product ID
 */
function pricode_create_product(){
    $product = new WC_Product_Variable();
    $product->set_description('T-shirt variable description');
    $product->set_name('T-shirt variable');
    $product->set_sku('test-shirt');
    $product->set_price(1);
    $product->set_regular_price(1);
    $product->set_stock_status();
    return $product->save();
}

/**
 * Create Product Attributes 
 * @param  string $name    Attribute name
 * @param  array $options Options values
 * @return Object          WC_Product_Attribute 
 */
function pricode_create_attributes( $name, $options ){
    $attributes = array();
    if(!empty($options)){
        if(is_string($options)){
            $term = wp_create_term(
                $options,
                wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($name)
            );
            if(is_array($term)){
                $attributes[] = (int)$term['term_id'];
            }
        }
        else{
            for($i = 0; $i < count($options); $i++){
                $term = wp_create_term(
                    $options[$i],
                    wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($name)
                );
                if(is_array($term)){
                    $attributes[] = (int)$term['term_id'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
    /*
        Set the attribute id to the id of the taxonomy to use
        with wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name you get the id of the taxonomy stored in {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies
        with wc_attribute_taxonomy_name you convert the Attribute name to the attribute name woocommerce use 
        @see https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name
        @see https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_attribute_taxonomy_name
    /*
    $attribute->set_id(wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name(wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($name)));
    $attribute->set_name(wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($name));
    $attribute->set_options($attributes);
    $attribute->set_visible(true);
    $attribute->set_variation(true);
    return $attribute;
}

/**
 * [pricode_create_variations description]
 * @param  [type] $product_id [description]
 * @param  [type] $values     [description]
 * @return [type]             [description]
 */
function pricode_create_variations( $product_id, $values ){
    $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
    $variation->set_parent_id( $product_id );
    $variation->set_attributes($values);
    $variation->set_status('publish');
    $variation->set_sku($data->sku);
    $variation->set_price($data->price);
    $variation->set_regular_price($data->price);
    $variation->set_stock_status();
    $variation->save();
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $product->save();

}
//Adding product
$product = pricode_create_product();

//Creating Attributes 
$atts = [];
$atts[] = pricode_create_attributes('color',['red', 'green']);
$atts[] = pricode_create_attributes('size',['S', 'M']);

//Adding attributes to the created product
$product->set_attributes( $atts );
$product->save();

//Create variations
pricode_create_variations( $product->get_id(), [wc_attribute_taxonomy_name('color') => sanitize_title('red'), wc_attribute_taxonomy_name('size') => sanitize_title('M')]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the write way to create variable product

```
// Name and image would be enough
```

$product = new WC_Product_Variable();

```
$product->set_name( 'Wizard Hat' );
$product->set_image_id( 90 );

// one available for variation attribute
$attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attribute->set_name( 'Magical' );
$attribute->set_options( array( 'Yes', 'No' ) );
$attribute->set_position( 0 );
$attribute->set_visible( true );
$attribute->set_variation( true ); // here it is
    
$product->set_attributes( array( $attribute ) );

// save the changes and go on
$product->save();

// now we need two variations for Magical and Non-magical Wizard hat
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation->set_parent_id( $product->get_id() );
$variation->set_attributes( array( 'magical' => 'Yes' ) );
$variation->set_regular_price( 1000000 ); // yep, magic hat is quite expensive
$variation->save();

$variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation->set_parent_id( $product->get_id() );
$variation->set_attributes( array( 'magical' => 'No' ) );
$variation->set_regular_price( 500 );
$variation->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

above answer (LoicTheAztec) helped me a lot but there was some issues instead of using

`update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, $term_slug );`

use :
`update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_'.$attribute, $term_name );`

because taxonomy is already is been modified and this is causing problem to update post meta after changing this update values and not selecting automatically in admin product variation edit after this changes it work great !

Comment: does this solve the issue where the term name is not being selected on variation on the admin?

Answer (score 0):

Coming in late to the party but adding to the answer from LoicTheAztec (which works perfectly) if your new variation does not end up with a selected attribute, use the following line just before the save method:

```
$variation->set_weight(''); //LoicTheAztec 

$variation->set_attributes($variation_data["attributes"]); // Select the attributes

$variation->save(); //LoicTheAztec
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted article works like a charm. If you manage to create the variations but it comes out without an option selected in the variation and when you try to save a single one resets to empty, I highly suggest checking this thread [Creating WooCommerce product variation adds an empty attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657703/creating-woocommerce-product-variation-adds-an-empty-attribute-value) , I ve been struggling with the same issue for over 2 hours. Happy coding

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [return_false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70835508/16369076) answer: since WC 3.0 in order to solve the issue where the term name is not being selected on variation on the admin you should use [set_default_attributes](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_set_default_attributes).

```
$variation->set_weight(''); //LoicTheAztec 
$variation->set_default_attributes($variation_data["attributes"]); // Select default attributes
$variation->save(); //LoicTheAztec
```