# Creating WooCommerce product variation adds an empty attribute value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

When adding variations to a WooCommerce product it is adding in a blank attribute. Meaning that when I try to add my own attribute it gets appended to an existing array.

Example code I am running:

```
$product_variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
$product_variation->set_attributes(array('attribute_pa_varinfo' => 'blue'));
$product_variation->save();
```

Then when I `var_dump($product_variation);` I get the following:

```
["attributes"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pa_varinfo"]=>
  string(4) "5034"
}
```

So when I view the product in WooCommerce admin all my variations are there but the attribute is stuck at "any option" for all of them.

[image: no option selected]

The weird thing is when I then "update" the product from wp-admin all of the variations then get the correct attribute selected.

Has anyone encountered this before or got any ideas of what I can do?

As another example, if I run the following:

```
$product_variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
$product_variation->set_attributes( array ( 'simon' => 'confused' ) );
$product_variation->save();
var_dump($product_variation->get_attributes());
```

This returns:

```
array(2) {
 [0]=> string(0) ""
 ["simon"]=> string(8) "confused"
}
```

Where does the first item come from? I can't seem to clear it.

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer… You can check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was with the actual setting up of the attribute against the main parent product, I was passing through an unnamed array, by adding `wc_attribute_taxonomy_name('varinfo') =>` (line 2 below) this correctly saves the data and removes the blank array I had.

```
      $product_attributes = array(
      wc_attribute_taxonomy_name('varinfo') => 
      array (
        'name'         => wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( 'varinfo' ), // set attribute name
        'value'        => '', // set attribute values
        'position'     => 1,
        'is_visible'   => 1,
        'is_variation' => 1,
        'is_taxonomy'  => 1
      )
    );

    update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update** *(related to your update and comments)*

> **To resume** *(our comments)*: The product attribute exist. Also all terms for this attribute are defined and set in the parent variable product *(in the "Attribute" settings tab)*

I have made some tests:

1. I have create a new 'Varinfo" attribute (`pa_varinfo`) with 4 values (term names): 
   `104 mm`, `110 mm`, `130 mm` and `140 mm` *(so term slugs are like `104-mm`…)*.
2. I have created a new variable product with one empty variation (nothing defined for this variation) and alter saving the select field shows: 
   [image]

When using this code (similar to yours):

```
$parent_product = wc_get_product( 738 ); // Get the variable product
$variation_ids = $parent_product->get_children(); // Get all children variations (Here only one)

// Iterating through each variation
foreach( $variation_ids as $variation_id ){
    $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
    $variation->set_attributes(array('pa_varinfo' => '104-mm'));
    $variation->save();
}
```

> **it's just working for me** and I get the selected value in backend for this variation:
> [image]

**Note** that I am using the **taxonomy name** for the attribute and the **term SLUG** in the array…

So I don't know **where you are doing something wrong**…

---

This happens when you set an attribute term that doesn't exist and/or is not registered as a post term of the parent variable product. You can try this:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
$variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

// Initialising variables
$taxonomy = 'pa_varinfo'; // The taxonomy
$term_name = 'Blue'; // The term "NAME"

// Check if the term exist and if not we create it.
if( ! term_exists( $term_name, $taxonomy ) )
    wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy );
    
// Get an instance of the WP_Term object
$term = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, $taxonomy );

// Get the post terms names from the parent variable product.
$post_term_names =  wp_get_post_terms( $variation->get_parent_id(), $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'names') );

// Check if the post term exist and if not we set it in the parent variable product.
if( ! in_array( $term_name, $post_term_names ) )
    wp_set_post_terms( $variation->get_parent_id(), $term_name, $taxonomy, true );

// Now you can set the term for the attribute in your variation
$variation->set_attributes( array( $taxonomy => $term->slug ) );
$variation->save(); // Registering the data

// Get an instance of the parent WC_Product_Variable object
$parent_product = wc_get_product( $variation->get_parent_id() );

// Sync the data of the variation in the parent variable product
$parent_product->sync( $variation_id );
```

This is tested and works

*Assuming that you have already created the appended attribute in WooCommerce…*, you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help @LoicTheAztec I tried that code and hoped that the sync function was what I was missing. Alas I am still stuck with the same issue that none of the variations are getting assigned the attributes. And I get the following: http://i.imgur.com/TnmTW0I.png

Comment: @SimonPollard Your question is not clear and explicit as you are not telling that it's in backend… My answer is related to front end. Now I will update my answer a bit later (for backend)…

Comment: apologies - I have re-written the question to be more clear and added the image - appreciate your help

Comment: My issue is the blank item in the attributes array - there should only be 1 record - no idea how / where it gets added

Comment: I deleted the 0000 attribute just in case - still no luck

Comment: yes all the terms are defined - I just need to assign the relevant one to the variation - it seems as soon as I add a variation it adds the blank attribute

Comment: @SimonPollard OK come back later… I might have something, but I need to make some testing before…

Comment: Thanks for your help - turns out the issue was with how I was adding the taxonomy to the product!

Answer (score 1):

Since WC 3.0 in order to get the variation selected you should use ***[set_default_attributes](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_set_default_attributes)***.

Instead of

```
$variation->set_attributes(array('varinfo' => '104-mm'));
```

Use

```
$variation->set_default_attributes(array('varinfo' => '104-mm'));
```