# Generated product variations connected to variable product does not display attributes in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on code that takes a CSV file and uploads its content to variable and variation products in WooCommerce. The code correctly links the variations to the variable products and also adds the appropriate attributes to the variable product. It also assigns the correct price, weight, etc. to the variations. However, when I monitor the variations page in WooCommerce, all the variation attributes are not set. Please help me resolve this. Any assistance would be appreciated. Ignore the `nordwebb_log` function in the code below; it's just for debugging.

I have followed the advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657703/creating-woocommerce-product-variation-adds-an-empty-attribute-value) with the same problem, but I didn't get it to work.

```
    if ($current_chunk <= $total_variable_chunks) {
 // We're in the variable products phase
 $current_data_chunk = array_slice($variable_products, ($current_chunk - 1) * $chunk_size, $chunk_size);
        
        
 foreach ($current_data_chunk as $row) {
     
        nordwebb_log("1");
     
     $product_data = array_combine($header, $row);
     
     nordwebb_log("2");
     
     // Creating a variable product
     $product = new WC_Product_Variable();
     $product->set_name($product_data['Namn']);
     $product->set_slug($product_data['Slut']);
     $product->set_regular_price($product_data['Ordinarie pris']);
     $product->set_short_description($product_data['Kort beskrivning']);
     $product->set_description($product_data['Beskrivning']); // Full product description
     $product->set_status('publish'); // Making the product published
     
         nordwebb_log($product);

     
     // Setting attributes for the variable product
     $attributes = array();

     // Attribute 1
     if (!empty($product_data['Attribut 1 namn']) && !empty($product_data['Attribut 1 värde(n)'])) {
         $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
         $attribute->set_name($product_data['Attribut 1 namn']);
         $attribute->set_options(explode(',', $product_data['Attribut 1 värde(n)'])); // Assuming '|' as delimiter for multiple values
         $attribute->set_position(0);
         $attribute->set_visible(true);
         $attribute->set_variation(true);
         $attributes[] = $attribute;
     }

     // Attribute 2 (similarly you can add more attributes if present)
     if (!empty($product_data['Attribut 2 namn']) && !empty($product_data['Attribut 2 värde(n)'])) {
         $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
         $attribute->set_name($product_data['Attribut 2 namn']);
         $attribute->set_options(explode(',', $product_data['Attribut 2 värde(n)']));
         $attribute->set_position(1);
         $attribute->set_visible(true);
         $attribute->set_variation(true);
         $attributes[] = $attribute;
     }

     $product->set_attributes($attributes);
     $product_id = $product->save();
     
     
             nordwebb_log($product_id);
     
     // Store the mapping of original CSV ID to WordPress product ID
     $id_mapping[$product_data['ID']] = $product_id;
    update_option('nordwebb_id_mapping', $id_mapping);
                 nordwebb_log($id_mapping);
     
 }

    } else {
         // We're in the variations phase
    $adjusted_chunk = $current_chunk - $total_variable_chunks;
    $current_data_chunk = array_slice($variations, ($adjusted_chunk - 1) * $chunk_size, $chunk_size);
    foreach ($current_data_chunk as $row) {
        nordwebb_log("3");
        
        $product_data = array_combine($header, $row);
        
        nordwebb_log("4");
        // Use the ID mapping to get the WooCommerce ID of the parent product
        $parent_id = $id_mapping[strval(intval(floatval($product_data['Överordnad'])))];
        
        nordwebb_log(strval(intval(floatval($product_data['Överordnad']))));
        
        // Create a new variation
        $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
        $variation->set_parent_id($parent_id);
        
        // Set attributes for this variation
        $attributes = [];
        if (!empty($product_data['Attribut 1 namn']) && !empty($product_data['Attribut 1 värde(n)'])) {
            $attributes[$product_data['Attribut 1 namn']] = $product_data['Attribut 1 värde(n)'];
        }
        if (!empty($product_data['Attribut 2 namn']) && !empty($product_data['Attribut 2 värde(n)'])) {
            $attributes[$product_data['Attribut 2 namn']] = $product_data['Attribut 2 värde(n)'];
        }
        
        nordwebb_log($attributes);
        
        $variation->set_attributes($attributes);
        
        // Set other details for this variation
        $variation->set_name($product_data['Namn']);
        $variation->set_description($product_data['Beskrivning']);
        $variation->set_short_description($product_data['Kort beskrivning']);
        $variation->set_sku($product_data['Artikelnummer']);
        $variation->set_regular_price($product_data['Ordinarie pris']);
        $variation->set_sale_price($product_data['Reapris']);
        
        // Stock settings (assuming unlimited stock for dropshipping)
        $variation->set_manage_stock(false);
        $variation->set_stock_status('instock');
        
        // Set dimensions & weight
        $variation->set_weight($product_data['Vikt (kg)']);
        $variation->set_length($product_data['Längd (cm)']);
        $variation->set_width($product_data['Bredd (cm)']);
        $variation->set_height($product_data['Höjd (cm)']);
        
        // Save the variation
        $variation->save();
    }
    }
```

EDIT: I tried to create a minimalistic example of the code but now the product that is created is not even a variable product:

```
<?php

// Simulated data from the CSV
$header = ['ID', 'Type', 'Name', 'Description', 'ShortDescription', 'RegularPrice', 'Attribute1Name', 'Attribute1Value', 'Attribute2Name', 'Attribute2Value', 'Parent'];

$variable_products = [
    [
        'ID' => 1000,
        'Type' => 'variable',
        'Name' => 'TESI 2:1',
        'Description' => 'Sample description for the variable product',
        'ShortDescription' => 'Sample short description',
        'RegularPrice' => '100',
        'Attribute1Name' => 'Size',
        'Attribute1Value' => '540x1800',
        'Attribute2Name' => 'Color',
        'Attribute2Value' => 'Flame Red Special R',
        'Parent' => ''
    ]
];

$variations = [
    [
        'ID' => 1001,
        'Type' => 'variation',
        'Name' => 'Different Name',
        'Description' => 'Sample description for the variation',
        'ShortDescription' => 'Sample short description for variation',
        'RegularPrice' => '90',
        'Attribute1Name' => 'Size',
        'Attribute1Value' => '540x1800',
        'Attribute2Name' => 'Color',
        'Attribute2Value' => 'Flame Red',
        'Parent' => 1000
    ]
];

// Simulated environment variables
$current_chunk = 1;
$total_variable_chunks = 1;
$chunk_size = 1;

// Placeholder for mapping original variable product IDs from CSV to actual product IDs in WordPress
$id_mapping = [];

if ($current_chunk <= $total_variable_chunks) {
    // We're in the variable products phase
    $current_data_chunk = array_slice($variable_products, ($current_chunk - 1) * $chunk_size, $chunk_size);
    
    foreach ($current_data_chunk as $row) {
        $product_data = array_combine($header, $row);
     
        // Creating a variable product
        $product = new WC_Product_Variable();
        $product->set_name($product_data['Name']);
        $product->set_regular_price($product_data['RegularPrice']);
        $product->set_short_description($product_data['ShortDescription']);
        $product->set_description($product_data['Description']);
        $product->set_status('publish');
     
        // Setting attributes for the variable product
        $attributes = [];

        // Attribute 1
        if (!empty($product_data['Attribute1Name']) && !empty($product_data['Attribute1Value'])) {
            $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
            $attribute->set_name($product_data['Attribute1Name']);
            $attribute->set_options(explode(',', $product_data['Attribute1Value']));
            $attribute->set_position(0);
            $attribute->set_visible(true);
            $attribute->set_variation(true);
            $attributes[] = $attribute;
        }

        // Attribute 2
        if (!empty($product_data['Attribute2Name']) && !empty($product_data['Attribute2Value'])) {
            $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
            $attribute->set_name($product_data['Attribute2Name']);
            $attribute->set_options(explode(',', $product_data['Attribute2Value']));
            $attribute->set_position(1);
            $attribute->set_visible(true);
            $attribute->set_variation(true);
            $attributes[] = $attribute;
        }

        $product->set_attributes($attributes);
        $product->set_type('variable');
        $product_id = $product->save();
     
        $id_mapping[$product_data['ID']] = $product_id;
    }
} else {
    // We're in the variations phase
    $adjusted_chunk = $current_chunk - $total_variable_chunks;
    $current_data_chunk = array_slice($variations, ($adjusted_chunk - 1) * $chunk_size, $chunk_size);
    
    foreach ($current_data_chunk as $row) {
        $product_data = array_combine($header, $row);
        
        $parent_id = $id_mapping[$product_data['Parent']];
        
        // Create a new variation
        $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
        $variation->set_parent_id($parent_id);
        
        // Set attributes for this variation
        $attributes = [];
        if (!empty($product_data['Attribute1Name']) && !empty($product_data['Attribute1Value'])) {
            $attributes[$product_data['Attribute1Name']] = $product_data['Attribute1Value'];
        }
        if (!empty($product_data['Attribute2Name']) && !empty($product_data['Attribute2Value'])) {
            $attributes[$product_data['Attribute2Name']] = $product_data['Attribute2Value'];
        }
        
        $variation->set_attributes($attributes);
        
        // Set other details for this variation
        $variation->set_name($product_data['Name']);
        $variation->set_description($product_data['Description']);
        $variation->set_short_description($product_data['ShortDescription']);
        $variation->set_regular_price($product_data['RegularPrice']);
        
        $variation->set_manage_stock(false);
        $variation->set_stock_status('instock');
        
        $variation->save();
    }
}
?>
```

[image: No attributes set for the products, but the attributes is there]

[image: The attributes is set up correctly]

Comment: Also, you should check in `wp_postmeta` database table, for a variation ID, to see how is set the variation attributes data and compare the data with a working variation. This thread can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518333/create-programmatically-a-variable-product-and-two-new-attributes-in-woocommerce/

Comment: @LoicTheAztec My apologies, I will write a reproducible example and edit the post. I will also add error handling as suggested.

Comment: No problem, but just saying that with the provided code and explanations, is not really possible to guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I recently attempted to create a reproducible example of my error and updated my post with the new code. The issue I'm encountering now is that the product generated is not a variable product, but rather a standard product. It's important to note that I have many more colors and sizes in the CSV file's attributes, and they are separated by commas. In my previous code, the generated product was a variable product, but it doesn't seem like I changed any logic related to that.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I managed to resolve the error using a variation of your response from the linked post. However, I now face another issue. On the product page, it displays 'pa_size' when I want it to show 'Storlek'. I attempted to change the attribute name, but this breaks the connection to the variants. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: If you use "Storlek" for Size in your language, you should start over and set from the beginning "Storlek" as attribute… Then the taxonomy to be used will be `pa_storlek`…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255396/discussion-between-julius-olsson-and-loictheaztec).