# Woocommerce Variations Through Hook

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook-woocommerce

I want to add variations on my website using wordpress.
I've tried a lot of plugins but they are not working according to my requirements.

**Requirements:**
I want to variate prices according to given variations:

```
1) Colors
2) Lining
3) Sizes
4) Leather Type
```

[image: Please check the image]

Anyone can refer plugin or function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518280/create-programmatically-a-woocommerce-product-variation-with-new-attribute-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create programmatically a WooCommerce product variation with new attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518280/create-programmatically-a-woocommerce-product-variation-with-new-attribute-value)

Comment: It's helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

-> Select **variable product** in product-data dropdown

-> Create 4 attributes 
 1. Color 
 2. Lining
 3. Size
 4. Leather Type
[image]
-> Goto variations and select **create variation from all attribute from the dropdown**
[image]
-> Add price to the variation and click on update

-> so now your product variation will look like this
[image]

-> Now you can design color and and lining as check boxes using this plugin 
[image]
Using the above steps and mentioned plugin will fill your requirement completly

Please accept as answer if it is helpfull to you
Thank You xD