# Woocommerce Add Product Variation as a Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I would want to add to my Plugin in the Woocommerce Product Page a Custom Field in the General Tab to add a new Product Variation( just Name, Price and short Description), I haven't found an answer on Stackoverflow, just how to create it programmaticaly, but whithout custom field. [Create programmatically a WooCommerce product variation with new attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518280/create-programmatically-a-woocommerce-product-variation-with-new-attribute-value) . Would appreciate every help for an answer! Best regards