# Create Woocommerce product attributes from XML in PHP ends up with empty values

Tags: php, xml, woocommerce

I have an XML with the following structure

```
<product>
  <sku>
    <![CDATA[ 11008269 ]]>
  </sku>
  <name>
    <![CDATA[MONTANA 165]]>
  </name>
  <price_ind>366.00</price_ind>
  <Filters>
    <filter>
        <group id="6">Material</group>
        <value id="2">Wood</value>
    </filter>
    <filter>
       <group id="7">Color</group>
       <value id="10">White</value>
    </filter>
    <filter>
      <group id="7">Color</group>
      <value id="11">Black</value>
    </filter>
    <filter>
      <group id="8">Usage</group>
      <value id="49">Outdoors</value>
    </filter>
  </Filters>
</product>
```

The filter nodes hold some product attributes.
I am trying to parse this XML and create the attributes in PHP. but it is failing. The attributes are added to the product without its corresponding values. The value is empty.

[image]

The attribute terms are getting added in the attribute though.

[image]

This is how I am trying to do it

```
 function create_attributes( $id, $xml) {

//create an array of the xml data
$record = json_decode( json_encode( (array) $xml ), true );
$count = count($product_attributes);
$i = 0;


if ( $record['Filters']['filter'] != null )
{
  //store existing product attributes in order not to get overwritten

  $product_attributes = get_post_meta($id, '_product_attributes',true);

  //iterate through the XML
  while( array_key_exists( $i, $record['Filters']['filter'] ) ) {
    
    if ( $record['Filters']['filter'][ $i ]['group'] == "Material" )
    {

     $attribute = "pa_material";
     wp_set_object_terms($id, $record['Filters']['filter'][ $i ]['value'], 'pa_material' , true);

    }
    else 
    if ( $record['Filters']['filter'][ $i ]['group'] == "Color" )
    {
        $attribute = "pa_color";
         wp_set_object_terms($id, $record['Filters']['filter'][ $i ]['value'], 'pa_color' , true);


    }
    if ( $record['Filters']['filter'][ $i ]['group'] == "Usage" )
    {
        $attribute = "pa_usage";
 
        wp_set_object_terms($id, $record['Filters']['filter'][ $i ]['value'], 'pa_usage' , true);


    }
    
    //build the attributes array
    $product_attributes[$attribute] = array(
     'name' => $attribute,
     'value' => $record['Filters']['filter'][ $i ]['value'],
     'position' => $count, 
        'is_visible' => '1',
'is_variation' => '0', 
'is_taxonomy' => '1');

        
    
    $i++;
    $count++;
}
                    
update_post_meta( $id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes ); }
```

Comment: Refer to this question [Create programmatically a WooCommerce product variation with new attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518280/create-programmatically-a-woocommerce-product-variation-with-new-attribute-value)