# How do I create a product with variations?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a product in php with variations. I've gotten the product creation but I can't seem to figure out how to create variations for it. Googling only returns adding variations to existing products, but I'm trying to create a product completely from scratch, give it an attribute, and using that attribute to make variations from an array of strings.

```
$team = get_post();     
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( 
        array( 'post_title' => $team->post_title,
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            )
        );
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'variable' );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', 'FEES-'.$team->ID );
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47766413/5772301

Comment: Not really, it didn't generate a variation of the product

Comment: @MarnieRodriguez, are you saying that you are unable to create a variation product from the code link of which is shared above? Because it creates a new variation product from scratch as you are trying to achieve. i can see that you have successfully created a variable product and the above code should be suffice to create variations and attach it to the parent which you created earlier. Can you explain why this isn't solving your problem ?

Comment: @Bhanu, the link provided is not creating a variation of the product. The above code IS creating a product that is a "variation product", but I'm trying to make a variation of that product. And example would be the above code making a shirt product, and now I'm trying to make a "red" shirt and "blue" shirt.

Comment: @MarnieRodriguez, the above code is actually making a `red shirt` and `blue shirt` using `shirt` see Usage (example with 2 attributes) in that answer. `$parent_id` is 746 (shirt) and attributes are defined at `$variation_data['attributes']`.

Comment: @Bhanu I'm sorry but its not working for me.

Comment: @MarnieRodriguez, update your question om how you tried the above code and I will try to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `"WC_Product_Variation"`class for registering variations and `wp_insert_post` for creating the product variable.

have a look at this example, it might help you or give an idea.

[Create WooCommerce Variable Product with Attributes](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/woocommerce-product-variations/)

See more info in woocommerce docs: [WC_Product_Variation](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product-Variation.html)