# How to programmatically create a Variable Product using existing Product Attributes

Tags: php, variables, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

Any advice would be most appreciated.
I have the following code that creates the Variable Product but the Attributes (and therefore the Variations) are not being attached.

```
$new_variable_product = new WC_Product_Variable();
 $new_variable_product->set_name("Book Your Event");
 $new_variable_product->set_slug($permalink);
 $new_variable_product->set_short_description('Hello world');
 $new_variable_product->set_status('publish');
 $new_variable_product->save();
 //*************************//
    $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
    
    // get a product attribute ID by name.
    $attribute_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( 'Event Purpose' );
    $attribute->set_id( $attribute_id );
    $attribute->set_name( 'pa_type-of-event' ); // -> removed 'pa_' prefix
    
    //Set terms slugs
    $attribute->set_options( array(
        'Hens Party', 'Social Party', 'Team Building'
    ) );
    $attribute->set_position( 0 );
    $attribute->set_visible( 1 );//If enabled
    $attribute->set_variation( 1 );//If we are going to use attribute in order to generate variations
    
    //Create the attribute2 object
    $attribute2 = new WC_Product_Attribute();
    
    // get a product attribute ID by name.
    $attribute_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( 'Estimated Guest No' );
    $attribute2->set_id( $attribute_id );
    $attribute2->set_name( 'pa_participants' ); // -> removed 'pa_' prefix
    
    //Set terms slugs
    $attribute2->set_options( array(
        '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'
    ) );
    $attribute2->set_position( 0 );
    $attribute2->set_visible( 1 );//If enabled
    $attribute2->set_variation( 1 );//If we are going to use attribute in order to generate variations
    
    $new_variable_product->set_attributes(array($attribute, $attribute2));
    
    //Save main product to get its id
    $thisid = $new_variable_product->save();
    
    $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
    $variation->set_regular_price($price);
    $variation->set_parent_id($thisid);
    
    //Set attributes requires a key/value containing
    // tax and term slug
    $variation->set_attributes(array(
        'pa_type-of-event' => '', 
        'pa_participants' => ''
    ));
    $variation->save();
```

There are existing Attributes with the name, as per below.
[image]

I have noticed that this line

```
$attribute_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( 'Event Purpose' );
```

is returning $attribute_id as 0. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create programmatically a WooCommerce product variation with new attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518280/create-programmatically-a-woocommerce-product-variation-with-new-attribute-value)

Comment: Hi Mr. Jo I have seen that post but it doesn't help my approach. I've tried following that solution and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

> I have noticed that this line
>
> ```
> $attribute_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( 'Event Purpose' );
> ```
>
> is returning $attribute_id as 0. Why?

Let me answer that part of your question, and then hopefully you can figure out the rest yourself.

#### Explanation

`wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name` internally works by, according to the [source code](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-attribute-functions.html#source-view.172):

1. Formatting the provided attribute name to a "slug"-friendly format (`Event Purpose -> event-purpose`)
2. Looking up all the defined taxonomies by their slug name to see if your inputted one exists there (checking if `event-purpose` slug exists)

   - if it DOES, return its ID
   - if it DOESN'T, return `0`

Looking at the screenshot you've posted, it's obvious that there's a mismatch between your custom-defined slug, `type-of-events`, and the one the functions uses, `event-purpose`.

The function's name *does* imply that it's looking up by its *name*, but that's not how it works internally, unfortunately.

#### Fix

- Change Event Purpose's **slug** to `event-purpose`

-- OR --

- Change the Attribute name to `Type of Event` (which will translate to `type-of-event` internally)

```
$attribute_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( 'Type of Event' );
```