# Auto Generate Products variations for all attributes in Woocommerce for all Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We have 6000 products in our WordPress site we added the Size attributes to all the variant products and made them Used for variations using a plugin called YITH WooCommerce Bulk Product Editing.

After we created assigning the attributes the 6000 products we discovered that the variations for these attributes hasn't been created automatically and the only way to generate them either by editing each product manually and go to Variation tab and then click on Generate variations for all Attributes or by using a plugin "https://elextensions.com/plugin/bulk-edit-products-prices-attributes-for-woocommerce/"

Is there a way to auto generate the products variations for all attributes with a code snippet or by MySQL query?

Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Check this answer if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/47766413/15306153

Comment: Thank you very much. That is not the solution for my case